# Remove prop property from button to validate my form

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a form form validation, that if my input is blank then button should be disabled. I am doing that by jquery and prop. But I think I am missing something. I have added my code below.

My ascx page

```
<input id="Name" type="text" class="Name" value="">

<button id="edit" disabled="disabled">Edit</button>
```

My Jquery

```
    function ValidationForm(){
        if ($.trim($('#Name').val()) === ''){
        return false;
      }
      else{
        return true;
      }
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#Name').keyup(function(e) {
          if (ValidationForm() === true){
            $('#edit').prop('disabled', true);
          }
          else {
            $('#edit').prop('disabled', false);
          }
      });
});
```

**Problem:**
Issue is when I am adding text to my input box button should get enabled which is not happening.

Comment: What behavior are you seeing that is wrong?

Comment: You need to interchange code between if else block.

Answer (score 0):

you have a misspelling in your if statement, its `if` not `id`

```
  if ($.trim($('#Name').val()) == ''){
    return false;
  }
  else{
    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keyup event to directly test the content of the input (without the named function) and use `$(this).val().trim()` to determine the content - then base the disabled state off that.

Also note that you are missing a name attribute for your text input meaning that it will not be passed via the form unless you are using an ajax call or other javascript to get the value of that input.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#Name').keyup(function(e) {
          if ($(this).val().trim() == ''){
            $('#edit').prop('disabled', true);
          }
          else {
            $('#edit').prop('disabled', false);
          }
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Name" type="text" class="Name" value="">

<button id="edit" disabled="disabled">Edit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that when validation is successful, you are setting the disabled property of your button as true. You need to interchange the code block inside if-else and also a closing parentheses was missing.

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#Name').keyup(function(e) {
              if (ValidationForm() === true) {
                  $('#edit').prop('disabled', false);
              } else {
                  $('#edit').prop('disabled', true);
              }
          }
      });
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and why it solves the problem will improve the answer's long-term value.